# How to send data from resolver in other route param in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

this is my resolver:

```
export class ComponentResolveService implements Resolve<Component> {
constructor(private componentService: ComponentService) {}

async resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<Component> {
    const id = Number(route.paramMap.get('id'));
    const type = route.data['type'];

    return this.componentService.getComponent(id, type);
}
```

}

and this is my routing object

```
{
     path: 'component/:id',
     component: Component,
     resolve: {
         data: dataResolver
     },
     data: {
         type: 'type',
         title: `{{data.title}}`,
         breadcrumbs: `{{data.title}}`
     },
}
```

and i try to send the data from resolver in title and breadcrums, you can see {{data.title}} but it doesn't. And can't find in official docs something related with that. It's possible somehow to send the data from resolver in title and breadcrumbs? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I assume router data is static and it's just merged with resolved data then available in component